# How to check if category has subcategories, and if yes display them c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building a website that at the moment has 2 tables: **Category** and **Post**.

*Category Table has:*

- CategoryId
- CategoryName

*Post Table has:*

- PostId
- PostName
- PostBody
- CategoryId

Everything is works, and if I clicking on each category it gives me full list of post that related to the category based on the `CategoryId` propety. However, I wants to add the feature of sub-category. I just don't sure about how to do it -> I wants to be able to add sub-categories, so if the user click on one of the category, it display all the subcategories (should I create another data base table for the subcategories or just use the current category table?), and if there is not subcategories to the current category, it will display the posts related to the category (like how he does it now). Any suggesions?

Comment: You have to create subcategory table, and load the same using category id

Comment: Or your categories may just have a Parent (nullable)

Comment: @OnyxCaldin What you meant by Parent? Can you have an example pleasE?

Comment: You have your answer in your question actually.

Comment: @satsvelke But how I can check if there is not subcaregories to this category, then display all posts related to this category? and I should change all post "categoryid" to the subcategory id then?

Comment: @WebR Well just add a field to Category table : ParentId. Properties having a ParentId are children of this parent category. All having null ParentId are top most categories

Comment: @OnyxCaldin Okay, but how the post will related to each subcategory? for example, if I have a subcategory y that related to category x, how i can display the posts of this subcategory only and not for the category?

Comment: @WebR well the CategoryId of the post will reference the subcategory not the category.

Comment: @OnyxCaldin And if I have a category without subcaregories? And I do wants the option of displaying post to the main category?

Comment: @WebR Categories and subcategories are the same object. Subcategories just have a reference to its parent. So if you want posts on subcategory, CategoryId will reference the subcategory. If you want posts on a category, CategoryId will reference the category.

Comment: @WebR add subcategoryid column to Post table, and fetch using subcategoryid when user clicks on subcategory